# Building Device Drivers "make" Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, make

I'm quite new to Linux Kernel Development, and I have an issue trying to build my device drivers so that I can test them and run the `strace` command on them. However, for some reason, in any directory (within the staging directory, such as greybus or netlogic), when I run the command `make`, I always get the same error. I'm using [this](http://kernelnewbies.org/FirstKernelPatch#head-a6e8b840a8d25c03fba491c4e20987973d5770f9) tutorial (header: Compiling only part of the kernel) which details the compiling process.

> make: *** No targets.  Stop.

I have no idea why this is showing up. Just, as an example, there is a Makefile in the greybus directory and it does have targets. This is the Makefile:

```
# Greybus core
greybus-y :=    core.o          \
                debugfs.o       \
                hd.o            \
                manifest.o      \
                module.o        \
                interface.o     \
                bundle.o        \
                connection.o    \
                control.o       \
                svc.o           \
                svc_watchdog.o  \
                operation.o

obj-$(CONFIG_GREYBUS)           += greybus.o

# needed for trace events
ccflags-y += -I$(src)


# Greybus Host controller drivers
gb-es2-y := es2.o
```

Comment: I see no targets in that Makefile.  A target is a line saying `something:` followed by target dependencies on the same line. Then there are lines with actions for building the target that are indented by tabs.  This Makefile fragment is probably included by another Makefile somewhere else.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought that the target was the greybus-y:.... part. Would that mean that I would have to compile one of its parent directories?

Comment: You need to stay in the top directory of the kernel (where you have subdirectories like kernel and drivers), and say for example `make path/file.o`, where path is the directory in which you found the above partial makefile.

Comment: No, those are variable assignments. I'm not familiar with the Linux kernel sources, so I can unfortunately not guide you to the correct way of doing what you want, but looking one level up or more may be needed, yes.

Comment: You want to do the build at the top level, probably after you have run `make menuconfig` to enable the greybus driver. Once you have done all this and installed the kernel you still *will not be able* to run strace on the driver. Strace shows the calls that userspace makes to the kernel, but the driver is in kernel space.

Comment: That makes sense, but why does it matter where I execute make from?

Comment: @Eames Well `make` will look for a Makefile in the current directory. That's why it matters. How else would it know what Makefile to pick?

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant, why does it have to be the top.

Comment: Because the "top" Makefile is the one which includes the rules and drives the build process. It is the one with the "all" traditional first target, but I repeat you will need to run "make menuconfig" or perhaps "make oldconfig" at the top first to create the .config file that says if things like greybus should be built at all, and if so should it be as a module to be loaded at runtime or built into the kernel.